# When using Generics, Parent Interface is requested and not inherited subclass

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlin-multiplatform

Summary:

- Attempting to build a generic interface, as the functionality is the same across different custom data types
- It is expecting the parent class rather than the inherited sub class

Question:

Moving from a single data type to multiple data types with matching functionality for each custom data type needed, using Generics. I am trying to refactor for the first function concrete and then implement the rest of the function concrete classes, after testing succeeds.

Simplified Structure:

- Function Interface: CustomInterface<T>

  - Function Concrete 1 - CustomInterface<CustomDataType1>
  - Function Concrete 2 - CustomInterface<CustomDataType2>
- Data Interface/List of Custom Data: CustomDataTypeRepository<T>

  - Data Concrete 1 - CustomDataType1
  - Data Concrete 2 - CustomDataType2

In refactoring, I have updated the function in the Interface from the single type 'Data Concrete 1' to generic 'CustomInterface'.

So far there is a 1-to-1 matching with the FC1/DC1 and FC2/DC2

I have tried a couple different design patterns, and the thing that is still not working is the expectation to have the parent type rather than the custom type that has been inherited. So I assume my code is working part from this expected generic type.

The IDE is requesting that I get CustomInterface<CustomerDataType1> rather than the expected subclass of the interface FunctionConcrete1. I have assumed that because you can inherit the class through the interface that this would work. I have seen in previous answers that this might not always be the case (in, out, etc. - which didn't seem to help me)

Seems to me like something to do with Generics in Kotlin that I am unsure about.

I wasn't sure if code was needed, but here is some pseudocode anyway:

```
interface CustomInterface<T> {
    fun calcSort(repo: Repository<T>, word: String): String
}

class FunctionConcrete1 : CustomInterface<CustomDataType1> {
    override fun calcSort(repo: CustomDataTypeRepository<CustomDataType1>, word: String) : String {
        return /* Return Sorted Information */
    }
}

fun calcSortAllInformation () {
    val customDataRepo : CustomDataTypeRepository<CustomDataType1> = /* Return a Stored List/Repository of Custom Data Type 1*/
    val sortString = FunctionConcrete1.calcSort(customDataRepo, /*word*/)
    // Requires the CustomDataTypeRepository<CustomDataType1>, 
    // rather than the inherited FunctionConcrete1
}
```

Hopefully that gives an idea of what is going on.
Thanks for any help. What would be a better way of doing this?

Minimum Reproducible Code:

```
interface SortInterface<T> {
    fun calcSort (repo: TestRepository<T>) : String
}
class SortConcrete : SortInterface<SimpleRepository>{

    override fun calcSort(repo: TestRepository<SimpleRepository>): String {
        println("Sorting Information")
        return "Info Sorted"
    }
}
interface TestRepository<T> {

    fun findAll(): Array<T>
}
class SimpleRepository : TestRepository<CustomDataType>{

    private val list = arrayOf(CustomDataType(),CustomDataType(2, "Second"))

    override fun findAll(): Array<CustomDataType> {
        return list
    }
}
data class CustomDataType (var num: Int = 1, var word: String = "STRING")

fun main(){
    val repo = SimpleRepository()
    val sortObject = SortConcrete()
    val sortedString = sortObject.calcSort(repo.findAll())
    println(sortedString)
}
```

This seems to show that the parent interface is needed, but I'm not quite sure it fully represents my case. It should at least be a start.
The 'sort' function is not implemented as it won't compile at the end.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? e.g. something that can be run on https://play.kotlinlang.org (Don't just post a link to that though, the question should be self-contained)

Comment: MRC has been added @Sweeper

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what went wrong originally.
Sorry for the above poorly written code. I imagine if I knew what the problem was it would have been easier to create a test case.

I had reset my code and started from slightly ahead with my designs.

What was different about this time was that I was able to use the Generics properly and directly for the types that I was expecting, rather than just their subtypes.

My original intention was to get the function to use the Parent Type in order to use the downstream object, in order to be 'more general'. Reducing and then using the specific subtype was what should have been intended.

Using my weird example:
So instead of using `CustomInterface<CustomDataType>` I should have directly used the intended subtype concrete class `FunctionConcrete1`.

This is a bit weird because the way that I was thinking was that I was able to use both the Concrete Class and the Interface Dependency interchangeably.
I'm not sure if that is still possible.

At least for the moment I am able to compile the code and continue with my work.

As above:

```
interface CustomInterface<T> {
    fun calcSort(repo: Repository<T>, word: String): String
}
```

As Expected - removed the Repository:

```
interface CustomInterface<T> {
    fun calcSort(repo: T, word: String): String
}
```

From here you can have your concrete class and use the subtypes within that to do as you expect.